# What is the meaning of * in CSS statements and when to use it?

Tags: css

Please consider below statements for example and explain the difference

```
.reveal * {display:none;}

.reveal *.handle {display:block;}
```

If I do not use * in first statement what difference it makes?

Comment: It's the "all element" selector and is usually going to include more than you mean to - hence it's a bad idea.

Comment: Its called the [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#universal-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first selector

```
.reveal * { ... }
```

the style applies to all decendents of the element with `class="reveal"`, but not that element itself. If you leave out `*` and write instead:

```
.reveal { ... }
```

the style applies to the `.reveal` element as well.

The second selector in your question is equivalent to

```
.reveal .handle { ... }
```

In this case, you can leave out `*` because there's another selector, and `*` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

`*` means everything!

Use it when you want a style to apply to EVERYTHING!

The difference between `*` and `*.handle` is `*` with apply to everything and `*.handle` will only apply to everything which has `.handle`

So in the case of your example css rules:

```
.reveal * {display:none;}
.reveal .handle {display:block;}
```

(Barmar makes a good point, *.handle is unnecessary, you can use: `.reveal .handle`)

Only those items with the class `handle` would be `display`ed

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hL4Yd/1/) to see it in action!

Comment: . symbol represents class selector right? And, if I do not use * in my first statement still it applies the style to all reveal class contents.

Comment: `.reveal *.handle` can also be written as `.reveal .handle`. You only need the `*` when there's no other selector.

Comment: yes, in CSS the `.` means "class" (# means "id").  Correct, your`*.handle` rule will still work.

Comment: that means both of below statements have same meaning i.e. .reveal * {display:none;} and .reveal {display:none;} Let me know if I am getting correct?

Comment: No, `.reveal *{}` hides all things INSIDE `.reveal`, whereas `.reveal{}` hides everything inside `.reveal` PLUS `.reveal` itself :)

Comment: Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hL4Yd/2/) too see how in `.reveal2` nothing is displayed because the `.reveal2` ITSELF is hidden!

Comment: Yeah... gl and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

"*" means "any possible element".  So:

```
.reveal * {display:none;}
```

Sets display:none (hide) everything inside the element with the class "reveal".  The element with the class "reveal" itself will remain visible, or whatever display happened to be.

```
.reveal *.handle {display:block;}
```

More specific that the first one, this trumps it.  Anything with a class of "handle" inside of that element with the class "reveal" will be set to display:block.

You asked about removing the "*" in the first one.  That's:

```
.reveal {display:none;}
```

That means that the element named "reveal" will itself be hidden.

My guess is that this code is operating on something like this:

```
<ul class="reveal">
  <li>This will be hidden</li>
  <li class="handle">This will not be hidden</li>
  <li>This is also hidden</li>
</ul>
```

Although the ul.reveal itself isn't doing much, it will be displayed (assuming no other CSS), so if you, say, added a border it will remain visible.